# Problem painting a map with Openlayers using Vue

Tags: vuejs2, openlayers

I'm writing an application in Vue that will have a map in it. I want to add some points in that map. The code relevant to the map is,

```
<div>
   <vl-map :load-tiles-while-animating="true" :load-tiles-while-interacting="true" data-projection="EPSG:4326" style="height: 400px">
     <vl-view :zoom.sync="zoom" :center.sync="center" :rotation.sync="rotation"></vl-view>
        <vl-layer-tile>
          <vl-source-osm></vl-source-osm>
        </vl-layer-tile>
        <vl-layer-vector>
          <vl-source-vector :features="points"></vl-source-vector>
        </vl-layer-vector>
   </vl-map>
</div>
```

Here `points` is part of data `points: []`
If I write the points directly in data everything works.
Like,

```
points: [
{
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
     type: 'Point',
     coordinates: [0.0, 0.0]
  },
  properties: {}
]
```

shows a point in `[0, 0]`.

However, I need to use a method that will call several APIs to find out the points that I need to show. It's when I write the code to prepare the `points` to have the correct value when everything stops working. I'm writing this code in the `mounted` section.

```
async calculatePoints () {
  this.points = // points as I want them to be
}
```

But this is not working (although some few times works). Any idea what is going on here or which is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Can you add the `points` value after it is calculated?

Comment: Points is a list. I'm adding elements there  on the calculatePoints methods using another list and pushing the elements one by one. At the end I just do that this other list is equal to this.points

Comment: I just want to check if there was anything weird in the features of the list, you think you can add a log of it?.

Comment: Yes, the logs show that everything is as expected. I think the problem might be that when the list is sent to the component, it is not ready yet, but when I write the logs, afterwards, it is. Does that make sense?